# Benefit of Android P Multi-Camera Support

Tags: android, android-camera, android-9.0-pie

Android P introduced multi-camera support: https://source.android.com/devices/camera/multi-camera. This allows developers to use multiple camera streams simultaneously as one camera ID can include multiple physical cameras now.

```
openCamera(multi_camera_logical_id);
createCaptureSession(multi_camera_session_configuration);
// Capture multi-camera
```

However, I'm wondering what's the exact benefit of this feature, because we can also access multiple streams simultaneously before Android P. It basically involves opening another camera with its camera ID, creating a capture session, and start capturing. This even sounds more flexible to me because we can configure two cameras/capture sessions instead of one.

```
openCamera(camera_id_1);
createCaptureSession(surfaces_1, callback_1, handler_1);
// Capture for camera ID 1

openCamera(camera_id_2);
createCaptureSession(surfaces_2, callback_2, handler_2);
// Capture for camera ID 2
```

I was thinking if the new API may save power because both cameras are in one capture session now. However, based on the speed of switching streams between different cameras in [the demo](https://miro.medium.com/max/960/0*WaZN9bicOXI4mpUp), I feel both camera streams must be running at the same time even if one is not presented on a surface.